# I am getting error in my python web application for watermarking a image

Tags: python, flask, python-imaging-library

I made a a web application with flask and in which I can adjust a text on a image and then download it but the problem is that the text just does not appears on the image but outside of it and is adjustable outside of image, I am unable to identify the problem and it would be really helpful if a developer can help

I tried java script to have draggable watermark functionality but when I try adding the watermark a canvas is created , the same size of the image outside of my image and there the watermark is adjustable, I was expecting that I can upload the image and adjust the text on the image and then download the image, but the only thing that is problematic is that the text just does not appears on the image but outside of the image, it would be really great if anyone could help me resolve this issue, please first try running the code yourself then you will understand what I am saying

app.py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import io
import base64

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    watermark_text = None
    text_color = None
    img_str = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        watermark_text = request.form['watermark_text']
        text_color = request.form['text_color']
        watermark_x = int(request.form['watermark_x'])
        watermark_y = int(request.form['watermark_y'])

        image = Image.open(request.files['image'])
        image.thumbnail((400, 400))

        buffered = io.BytesIO()

        # draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        # font = ImageFont.load_default()
        # 
        # draw.text((watermark_x, watermark_y), watermark_text, fill=text_color, font=font)
        image.save(buffered, format="PNG")

        img_str = base64.b64encode(buffered.getvalue()).decode()

    return render_template('index.html', watermark_text=watermark_text, text_color=text_color,       img_str=img_str)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Watermarking App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">

</head>
<body>
    <h1>Image Watermarking App</h1>

    <form id="watermark-form" action="/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="image">Upload Image:</label>
        <input type="file" name="image" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif, .bmp"><br>

        <label for="watermark_text">Watermark Text:</label>
        <input type="text" name="watermark_text" id="watermark-text" value="{{ watermark_text }}"><br>

        <label for="text_color">Text Color:</label>
        <input type="color" name="text_color" id="text-color" value="{{ text_color }}"><br>

        <input type="hidden" name="watermark_x" id="watermark-x" value="0">
        <input type="hidden" name="watermark_y" id="watermark-y" value="0">

        <input type="submit" value="Add Watermark">
    </form>

    {% if img_str %}
    <div id="watermarked-image-container">
        <h2>Watermarked Image:</h2>
        <div id="watermarked-image-wrapper">
            <img id="watermarked-image" src="data:image/png;base64,{{ img_str }}" alt="Watermarked Image">
            <div id="hovering-watermark" class="watermark-text">{{ watermark_text }}</div>
        </div>
        <button id="save-button">Save Watermarked Image</button>
    </div>
    {% endif %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='script.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

styles.css

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 20px;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

#watermark-form {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

label, input {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#watermarked-image-container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#watermarked-image {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.watermark-text {
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    padding: 5px;
    user-select: none;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    cursor: move;
}

#save-button {
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: #007bff;
    color: white;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#save-button:hover {
    background-color: #0056b3;
}
```

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let isDragging = false;
    let offsetX, offsetY;
    let hoveringWatermark;

    hoveringWatermark = $("#hovering-watermark");
    hoveringWatermark.on("mousedown", function (event) {
        isDragging = true;
        offsetX = event.clientX - parseInt(hoveringWatermark.css("left"));
        offsetY = event.clientY - parseInt(hoveringWatermark.css("top"));
    });

    $(document).on("mousemove", function (event) {
        if (isDragging) {
            let x = event.clientX - offsetX;
            let y = event.clientY - offsetY;

            let imageContainer = $("#watermarked-image");
            let maxX = imageContainer.width() - hoveringWatermark.width();
            let maxY = imageContainer.height() - hoveringWatermark.height();

            x = Math.min(Math.max(x, 0), maxX);
            y = Math.min(Math.max(y, 0), maxY);

            hoveringWatermark.css({ left: x, top: y });

            $("#watermark-x").val(x);
            $("#watermark-y").val(y);
        }
    });

    $(document).on("mouseup", function () {
        isDragging = false;
    });

    $("#save-button").on("click", function () {
        let watermarkX = $("#watermark-x").val();
        let watermarkY = $("#watermark-y").val();

        let watermarkImage = $("#watermarked-image");
        let image = new Image();
        image.src = watermarkImage.attr("src");

        image.onload = function () {
            let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;
            canvas.style.position = "absolute";
            canvas.style.left = watermarkImage.position().left + "px";
            canvas.style.top = watermarkImage.position().top + "px";

            let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

            context.font = "12px Arial";
            context.fillStyle = $("#text-color").val();
            context.fillText($("#watermark-text").val(), watermarkX, watermarkY);

            let link = document.createElement("a");
            link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            link.download = "watermarked_image.png";
            link.click();
        };
    });
});
```

you can upload the image and you can download it with the watermark on it but the only thing is that the text does not appears on the exact image but on outer canvas , so dont get confused just adjust the watermark where it is adjustable and save the image and you will understand